# mkdir function throw exception 'File exists' even after checking that directory doesn't exist

Tags: php, mkdir

I stumbled upon a every strange behaviour with mkdir function in PHP. Below is an example of my simple code.

```
$filepath = '/media/static/css/common.css';
if (!file_exists(dirname($filepath)))
{
   mkdir(dirname($filepath), 0777, TRUE);
}
```

'media' folder always exists. All folders into the 'media' folder have to be created. Before coping the common.css file I'd like to create a folder '/static/css'.

mkdir OCCASIONALLY throw  exception "File exists". I tried to create a folder if it doesn't exist. 'File exists' is a common error, I assume, so the folder exists.

I understand that there is a very little info I gave you and it is really strange error. Maybe you can give me any advice what I have to do and how I can test that bug and find the bottleneck.

Server: CentOS release 6.4

Thank you.

Comment: You might want to try PHP's [`is_dir()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-dir.php) instead of `file_exists()`. It checks for directories rather than files.

Comment: @showdev Unfortunately the same problem exists.

Comment: You are creating the dir in the root instead of the working folder

Comment: What is the output of `var_dump(is_dir('/media/static/css/'))`?

Comment: If you have multiple clients calling the php file simultaneously, the multiple instances of the script may all get false from file_exists, and then in parallel try to call mkdir (where all but the first script to win the race will get the exception)

Comment: $filepath = getcwd().'/media/static/css/common.css';
if (!is_dir(dirname($filepath)))
{
   mkdir(dirname($filepath), 0777, TRUE);
}

Comment: @faffaffaff It was the first my thought. And 'Yes', I have multiple clients calling the php file simultaneously. But how can I sort it out? What have I to do to support it?

Comment: @RobertRozas I have DOCROOT path. I cut it just for example.

Comment: Just dissable errors or warnings at the beggining of your php script

Comment: @RobertRozas I am not sure that it is correct way. 'mkdir' throw an exception. I can catch it, but still, the folder is not created and I can not copy a file in that folder.

Comment: You are in a race to create a folder(many users)...just one person can create that folder..i don't understand the real problem....maybe with an else...if (is_dir()){}else{copy file on that folder}??

Comment: `mkdir` does not throwing any exceptions.

Comment: @Hackerman wrote : "You are creating the dir in the root instead of the working folder" and I upvoted it, but in fact it is wrong, the dir is being created in /media/static/css/, the working dir, not the root dir because dirname('/media/static/css/common.css') == '/media/static/css/'

Answer (score 11):

This is a race condition situation. You should do something like that :

```
$filepath = '/media/static/css/common.css';
// is_dir is more appropriate than file_exists here
if (!is_dir(dirname($filepath))) {
    if (true !== @mkdir(dirname($filepath), 0777, TRUE)) {
        if (is_dir(dirname($filepath))) {
            // The directory was created by a concurrent process, so do nothing, keep calm and carry on
        } else {
            // There is another problem, we manage it (you could manage it with exceptions as well)
            $error = error_get_last();
            trigger_error($error['message'], E_USER_WARNING);
        }
    }
}
```

ref :

- https://www.drupal.org/files/1642532-drush-mkdir-race-condition.patch
- https://github.com/KnpLabs/Gaufrette/blob/master/src/Gaufrette/Adapter/Local.php#L260
- https://github.com/symfony/symfony/commit/04834521f1298c8fee2704b1c4b1df43b655eb60

Comment: Is there any advantage to using is_dir if you are suppressing mkdir errors anyway? Saving CPU cycles or something from always executing mkdir?

Comment: which is_dir are you talking about ? First one or second one ?

Comment: Very first is_dir check

Comment: You can do both, I think. I don't know about performance. It just seemed cleaner this way when I wrote it.

Comment: You should use filesystem abstraction by the way :)  https://github.com/thephpleague/flysystem/blob/master/src/Adapter/Local.php#L361